# how to parse a string into date?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

what is the format in SimpleDateFormat for parsing a string ie 07/12/2013 into a date type? I am using the following code, but desired format is not comimg.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
Date notBeforeDate ,notAfterDate; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
notBeforeDate = (Date)formatter.parse(notBeforeValue);  
notAfterDate = (Date)formatter.parse(notAfterValue);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking for a Java solution. Change the format string :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse("07/12/2013");
```

Refer the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the exact format string information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); ; 
Date notBeforeDate ,notAfterDate; 
notBeforeDate =formatter.parse("Your String format Date");  
notAfterDate =formatter.parse("Your String format Date");
```

[Read More](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).
Hope it will help you.